# How to create multiple if statements with meeting specific criterias such as date ranges based off of TODAY()'s date

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I've created a spreadsheet and would like to create an IF statement that will populate the cell with text (low, medium, high) if a certain criteria is met. For example, I'm tracking sub-assemblies that are due from our outsourcing vendors based off of specific due dates.

**Condition 1:** If an assembly is due within 7 days of today's date, then I want the cell to populate with the text "Low".
**Condition 2:** If an assembly is due within 3 days from today's date, then I want the cell to populate with the text "Medium".
**Condition 3:** If an assembly is due today, then I want the cell to populate with the text "High".

Here is what I have, but I'm only coming up with a "FALSE" return. `=IF(C155>TODAY()+7,"LOW",IF(C155>TODAY()+3,"MEDIUM",IF(C155=TODAY(),"HIGH")))`

Comment: You are not accounting for the days from today to 3 days from today, try `=IF(C155>TODAY()+7,"LOW",IF(C155>TODAY()+3,"MEDIUM",IF(C155>=TODAY(),"HIGH")))`

Comment: Thanks you for your help. It now works for all criteria. The only thing I'm getting now is a return of "False" for anything outside the range of specified criteria. Meaning, I needed to create a criteria that returns nothing ("") outside the 3 conditions specified earlier.

Comment: `=IF(C155>TODAY()+7,"LOW",IF(C155>TODAY()+3,"MEDIUM",IF(C155>=TODAY(),"HIGH","")))`

Answer (score 0):

To make this more maintainable, I would suggest a little helper/lookup table:

[image: Helper Table]

Then, you can use a `VLOOKUP` (taking advantage of the `range_lookup` parameter being set to `TRUE`) wrapped with `IFERROR`:

[image: Results]